# unable to upload file on server "Error 500 Inter server Error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am stuck in upload file it works fine on local but when I deploy on server it show

> 500 internal server Error..

Here its my code please review..where m wrong?

Here's my controller code

```html
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GlovalValues(Global_values REC, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
    string strPath = "~/Laptop_File/";
    string Server_path = "";
    string GetFileName = "";

    int id = REC.ID;
    string Desc = REC.GS_Desc;
    string Name = REC.GS_Name;
    string values = REC.GS_Values;
    int Effrows = 0;

    if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(strPath)))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(strPath));
            }
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                var filePath = Request.FilePath;

                var FileExtension = uploadFile.FileName.Substring(uploadFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower();

                string ActualFileName = uploadFile.FileName;

                GetFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uploadFile.FileName);


                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string UploadFileName = Path.GetFileName(GetFileName + "." + FileExtension);
                    Server_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Laptop_File/"), UploadFileName);

                    if (FileExtension == "xlsx" || FileExtension == "xltx" || FileExtension == "xls" ||      FileExtension == "xlt ")
                    {
                        file.SaveAs(Server_path);
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Global_Values_List", "GS_Global_Values");
}
```

here's my view

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("GlovalValues", "GS_Global_Values", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "id", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Uplaod File : </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile"  id="fileupload" />
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
             <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
          </div>
     </div>
}
```

Please help I cant figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 4):

In my case it reason from permission.When I ran my project locally on IIS Express everything was fine,and I could upload files correctly, but when I deployed it on IIS 8,it had returned me "Error 500 Internal server Error" for file uploading.
I have changed the permissions for "IIS_IUSRS" on "upload" folder in IIS 8 as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check on server that your application pool has rights of network services or other user with higher authority to Modify the directory & file writing. 
If your code is working in local this seems the only issue at moments.